# Angular 6, keeps returning error message "Http failure response for [url here]: 0 Unknown Error" after HttpClient request

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, angular6

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to make a request using angular 6 HttpClient but it is giving me the response

```
ERROR 
{…}
​
error: error { target: XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, … }
​
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0) }
​
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8088/home: 0 Unknown Error"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 0
​
statusText: "Unknown Error"
​
url: "http://localhost:8088/home"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
vendor.js:43414:33
```

I've written the back end in expressjs, and I've added the headers to allow cross origin access

How I know that this was a problem specific to angular was that I 
1. Wrote test code in Java to make the http call to the server (which worked). 
2. I made the call directly from my browser in which I got the expected response.

Express App :

```
app.all('*', function(res,req,next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://localhost:4200');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type');
    next();
});

app.listen(portNumber,(error)=>{
    if (error) throw error
    console.log("Now listening on port "+portNumber+" for server : localhost")
})

app.get("/home",(req,res)=>{
    res.status(400);
    res.send({name:"colin",age:10});
})
```

Angular App :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      })
    };
    let data = this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8088/home', httpOptions).subscribe();
    console.log(data);
  }
```

The test I've written in java ( I wrote this to ensure it is not an issue with just the server ) :

```
try
            {
            link = "http://localhost:8088/home";
            link = link.replaceAll("\\s","%20"); // replace all space with %20 that is recognizable by http
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            try
            {
                rd =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            } catch (ConnectException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(result.toString());
```

And the response ?

```
{"name":"colin","age":10}
```

Comment: Multiple issues with your code, but most glaring ones are 1) that is nog how you get data (should be inside sub) and 2) why are you sending a 400 status from express?

Comment: I was pretty much trying everything to see what will happen, and also, even when I use ```.subscribe((data)=>{});``` it still gives me same error.

Answer (score 0):

your response is in the asynchronous callback of the call:

```
.subscribe(response => {
  // do smth with it
});
```